# How to share customer account globally in magento

Tags: magento

I'm trying to share my customer account Globally:

I have two stores :

```
www.mainstore.com

store1.mainstore.com
```

I want to add functionality that if customer register any of the store can have access to login any store with same details.

To activate this made some changes in `admin panel > system > configuration > customer configuration > Account Sharing Option > Share Customer Accounts > Global`.

After changing the setting to Global when i click on save Config button i got below error :
**Error :** `Cannot share customer accounts globally because some customer accounts with the same emails exist on multiple websites and cannot be merged.`

[image]

Why i am getting this error ?
Suggest me the solution for this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run this code within your MySQL database. It works for me. And also you can try [this](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/merge-multiple-store-customers-to-master-store.html)

```
SET SESSION old_alter_table=1;
ALTER IGNORE TABLE customer_entity ADD UNIQUE INDEX duplicate_email (email);
```